# Filemaker calculation field in portal not being displayed as expected

Tags: filemaker

I have a database in Filemaker with forms that is connected to a MySQL database to work with.

I have created a portal that shows all invoices records from a Customer. So, the relationship between such tables is done. The Portal shows the records but I have Calculations Fields that calculates the total amount for that Invoice. This imply that for each record, that calculation Field should be independent from the set of records of invoices for that Customer.

In my situation, Calculation Fields in every record shows the same calc, when it should be different, because each one has it's own values for 'Units' and 'Price' fields.

What's the problem? What's missing?

regards.

Comment: What table are the calculation fields in? Also, what are the calculations?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information for a FileMaker question.  We need to know which table the layout is based on, which table the portal is based on, which table the calculation field is in, and which fields are in the calculation field's calculation.

I suspect you're probably running into a common misapprehension about portals.  Portals aren't independent views on related records.  They are views on records related to the current record.  This has a couple of implications.  Primarily, you can never look "back" through the portal to a nearer table on the relationship graph to see a related record.

For example, if you have a relationship graph like so:

```
TableA --|| TableB --|| TableC
```

If you base a layout on Table A, then place a portal on that layout from TableC, then place a field in that portal from TableB, the field from TableB will show the same value in every portal row.  You can't nest portals, so what you're seeing in the field from TableB is the first record related to TableA.  The view on TableC is created by asking which records are related to TableA.

I'm probably not explaining this clearly, but hopefully it's enough to give you a hint.

By the way, you can't do the sort of three-way table join that you might like to do if you're familiar with SQL.  You can't `SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON a = b JOIN C on a = c`.  Can't be done with portals.  It can be done with the ExecuteSQL function, but it's harder to display that on a layout.